# Trying to create Mock Object for DiscordSocketClient and its properties

Tags: c#, nunit, moq, discord.net

I am working on a discord bot project written in c# and currently trying to implement unit tests for the system using NUnit and Moq. For one of the features I need to access the server roles, which is done by 
`client.Guilds.First().Roles.Where(r => r.Name.Equals(roleName)).FirstOrDefault();` (ListManager.ModifyPermission, Line 116 ListManager.cs). 
The `client` object is a instance of DiscordSocketClient from the Discord.Net library and is passed into the constructor of the class, the roles are accessed in, via dependency injection. So specifically I need `client.Guilds.First().Roles` to return a Collection filled with two mocked roles in it. My Problem however is, that Moq doesn't support mocking of non-virtual classes like SocketRole, or SocketGuild (container for a guild object). They each implement a corresponding interface (IRole, IGuild), however it is not possible to convert from the Interface to its related class. 
[The entire code can be accessed here](https://github.com/M4N1/Community-Discord-BOT). Affected is the [ListManager](https://github.com/M4N1/Community-Discord-BOT/blob/master/CommunityBot/Features/Lists/ListManager.cs) class. [ListManagerTestsHelper](https://github.com/M4N1/Community-Discord-BOT/blob/master/CommunityBot.NUnit.Tests/FeatureTests/ListManagerTests/ListManagerTestsHelper.cs).GetDiscordSocketClient is where the mocking of the client should happen. I already thought about passing a list of the existing roles directly into the ListManager class, however the dependency injection is set up before the DiscordSocketClient connects, therefore there are no roles assigned to it at the point in time of setup.

**Edit:** 
Generally I only need to know, if there is a way to return a Collection<Interface> from a mocked object, even though the actual object should return Collection<ObjectThatImplementsInterface>, because the Interface contains all the data that is needed for the test and the actual method that uses it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can change the field:

```
private readonly DiscordSocketClient client;
```

in the `ListManager` into just the guilds, that is:

```
private readonly IReadOnlyCollection<IGuild> guilds;
```

and then of course change its constructor accordingly.

Then you do just:

```
guilds.First().Roles.Where(r => r.Name.Equals(roleName)).FirstOrDefault()
```

or equivalently:

```
guilds.First().Roles.FirstOrDefault(r => r.Name == roleName)
```

I think you should be able to pass in `client.Guilds` when you construct the `ListManager` from your "real" code. That is because of nice covariance of the `IReadOnlyCollection<out T>` type.

In your test, you can just pass a `new[] { guildMoq1.Object, guildMoq2.Object, }` where `guildMoq1` etc. is a `Mock<IGuild>` where you have setup the `.Roles` as desired (again you should be able to use just a `new [] { ... }` for setting up `.Roles`).

---

**Edit:**

Maybe in the `ListManager` use a `Func<>`:

```
private readonly Func<IReadOnlyCollection<IGuild>> getGuilds;
```

and the same `Func<>` in the signature of the constructor. Then that constructor argument can be given as:

```
() => client.Guilds
```

from your "real code". In this way you can construct your `ListManager` already at a time when `client.Guilds` is not ready to be asked yet. The `client` reference will be "captured" in the `Func<>` (closure semantics).

In the test, you can use:

```
() => new[] { guildMoq1.Object, guildMoq2.Object, }
```

where `guildMoq1` etc. are as before?

Of course the line in `ListManager` will now look like this:

```
getGuilds().First().Roles.FirstOrDefault(r => r.Name == roleName)
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Problem with that is the same as passing the collection of roles in there, that at the time of creating ListManager, the client isn't connected yet and hence has no collection of SocketGuild available. But since this is causing so many problems, I will try to refactor the ListManager class, so that I don't need to access the client data inside of the class. Hopefully that will work out. Thank you for your help anyway.

Comment: Ah, you would want a `Func<IReadOnlyCollection<IGuild>>` then, maybe? Will edit.